# Is there an @inheritDoc equivalent in Doxygen?

Tags: javadoc, doxygen, documentation-generation

I know Javadoc will compile {@inheritDoc}, but what's the Doxygen way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's the explicit [copydoc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) which I think is closest to an equivalent although with more flexibility it therefore requires you specify the original to copy so is a bit more awkward. It's designed to let you pull in documentation from **anywhere** so it needs a parameter specifying the source.

[By default](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc), the default is to inherit documentation from parent classes.

Answer (score 16):

With [INHERIT_DOCS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_inherit_docs) set to YES in your Doxygen configuration file (which is actually the default), just leave your overridden members *completely uncommented* and Doxygen will automatically insert the documentation from the base class.

[@copydoc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) is useful for the case where you want to inherit base class comments, but then add some subclass-specific details.

Comment: How do you add the subclass-specific details?