Doxygen inherit some of the arguments in another function
I am surprised that Doxygen seems unable to inherit function arguments from another documented function. Say I've already documented f:
/**
 * Add them
 * 
 * Add them
 * 
 * @param a  An integer.
 * 
 * @param b  An integer.
 * 
 * @param c  An integer.
 * 
 * @return  Return the sum.
 *
 */
int f(int a, int b, int c) { return a + b + c; }

Now I want to document another function with the same a and b from f. Using roxygen2 for documenting C++ function exposed through Rcpp module, I can write the following:
/**
 * Do something
 * 
 * Do something
 * 
 * @inheritParams f
 * 
 * @param d  A double
 * 
 * @return  Return the result.
 * 
 */
double g(int a, int b, double d} { return (a + b) * d; }

The above code will inherit the description of a and b from f.
I have so many functions whose arguments are more or less the same. Copying and pasting the parameter description is quite daunting. How to achieve function parameter inheritance in Doxygen in 2024?
Thank you!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5613028/5494370

Which version of doxygen are you using?

The @copydoc has as disadvantage that it will copy not only all parameters, resulting in a warning for parameter c, but also the brief and detailed description etc. (see the function g below)
Doxygen is lacking, at the moment,  a @copyparam command, but with the \snippet{doc} command there are some possibilities as shown in the example below (result in function g1).

we need the placeholders for the snippet command to indicate which part to be coped (the [f_p] parts in the function f. We also use the \noop command here so the [f_p] won't show up in the documentation of f
the part between the placeholders should not have the * as otherwise these would appear in the resulting output of g1 as list markers.
in the function g1 we need the reference: @snippet{doc} aa.h f_p so the snippet is included as documentation (my file is aa.h hence the name in the command).

It all has been tested with the current doxygen version 1.10.0 (due to a problem in doxygen 1.10.0 the construct @snippet{doc} this f_p is not possible and hence the explicit file name in @snippet{doc} aa.h f_p)
/// \file


/**
 * Add them
 *
 * Add them
 * \noop [f_p]
   @param a  An integer.

   @param b  An integer.
   \noop [f_p]
 *
 * @param c  An integer.
 *
 * @return  Return the sum.
 *
 */
int f(int a, int b, int c) { return a + b + c; }

/**
 * Do something
 *
 * Do something
 *
 * @copydoc f
 *
 * @param d  A double
 *
 * @return  Return the result.
 *
 */
double g(int a, int b, double d) { return (a + b) * d; }

/**
 * Do something
 *
 * Do something
 *
 * @snippet{doc} aa.h f_p
 * @param d  A double
 *
 * @return  Return the result.
 *
 */
double g1(int a, int b, double d) { return (a + b) * d; }

Result:




Not what I wanted, but thanks for the answer. Do you think Doxygen will ever implement @inheritParams?

I don't think the @inheritParam will be implemented (due to the fact that it can parameters that are not in the target (in this case the parameter c). Regarding \copyparam I'm a bit optimistic, but probably wiln need a good concept also in relation to other parts in the detailed description (like e.g the return part, throw etc.).

Thank you for the information. As the days go by this problem has become more annoying :D Since you have much more experience with Doxygen, have you been in a situation where u have to document numerous functions with a lot of arguments that are more or less identical? If you have, without the @inheritParams functionality, how did you circumvent the drama of copy and paste?
